# Secondary additions to a Barleywine

Tags: beer, secondary-fermentation

I'm brewing a Barleywine soon and wanted to add something to the secondary  to make it interesting.  I was thinking of doing some bourbon soaked oak cubes, but was also thinking some fruit would be good as well.  Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was your original specific gravity and your final specific gravity?  I only ask that vs ABV just to get a handle on how sugary the beer might be in its attenuated form.

Comment: I haven't brewed it yet and still working on the recipe.  I think we're shooting for 13%

Comment: But what will FG be, according to the recipe? It matters a lot with respect to what will be great additions.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have 3 tones you could go with.

herbal: cardamom, nutmeg, allspice or star anise.
this might be a nice little warm note over the hops.

fruity: orange or lemon zest, or stone fruit(cherries, apricots, etc)

or extra bitter: Wormwood if you are a masochist

taste your wort to what it needs for good balance. I have a hard time making high gravity beers because they have bad balance and taste like bananas and vanilla, but good luck to you!